# Problema con renderizado de componente en vue.js y axios

Tags: php, vue.js

tengo el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servidor me responde: `<h1>Hola !!!</h1> <br> <p>Bienvenido a Vue.js</p>`

**Cuando se ejecuta en el navegador pasa lo siguiente:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como puedo hacer para que me muestre asi y no como un texto:** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede dar alguna sugerencia se los agradezco mucho

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para que vue renderize el HTML correctamente debes usar la directiva v-html.
[Documentación de vuejs RawHtml.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Debes hacer esto:

```
<template id="saludo">
  <div v-html="componentSaludo"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: por favor agrega un ejemplo en código que explique lo que tiene tu enlace; pues solo colocar links se considera de baja calidad